# Find consecutive zeroes in a row

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataset with sales by months and I need to find clients which stoped buying.

```
Clients     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
Client 1    123 768 678 452 213 123 55  10  0   0   0   0
Client 2    549 542 21  321 31  59  998 0   546 980 0   987
Client 3    500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0
Client 4    126 545 2315    268 126 56  0   0   0   0   0   
Client 5    546 546 0   0   0   328 486 326 0   0   66  0
Client 6    0   0   0   25  78  563 698 631 230 53  0   0
```

So, I assume that client 1 and client 4 stopped working with us, how can I find them? Or how can i find rows with more than 3 consecutive zeroes?

Comment: its better if, you provide a dataset as well. you can get quick reply.

Comment: Though you can sum up last 3 columns and say if the answer is less than 1 for reproducible code than client stopped working with you.

Comment: https://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: Can you define more precisely what is the precise sign of "stop working with us"? Is three zeros only a sign (like, row 5 and 6 has three zeros then numbers)?

Comment: Ronak Shah, Yes, clients 1 and 4, sorry.

Comment: Maybe as matrix, add two more matrices with all values rotated one place right and two places right, summ the three matrices and look for zeroes

Comment: @ColinFAY, That is the most difficulc question here. Lost are the clients that've started the year with us, but after some month they stoped buying and've got only zeroes after that, but no less than 3.  Maybe we should give some statuses to the clients: regular - buys always, irregular - have some zeros, but no more than 5, indangered - he've got more than 5 zeros, but the last one was no mor than 3 monthes before the end of the year, and the lost clients - they are the clients which stoped buying in on month? more than 3 monthes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Had to fix Client 4, one number was missing
DF <- read.table(text = 'Clients     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
                 "Client 1"    123 768 678 452 213 123 55  10  0   0   0   0
                 "Client 2"    549 542 21  321 31  59  998 0   546 980 0   987
                 "Client 3"    500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0   500 0
                 "Client 4"    126 545 2315 27  268 126 56  0   0   0   0   0   
                 "Client 5"    546 546 0   0   0   328 486 326 0   0   66  0
                 "Client 6"    0   0   0   25  78  563 698 631 230 53  0   0', header = TRUE)
```

Loop over rows, reverse the order, and find which entry is the first non-zero; if the client never head a transaction return `length(x)`:

```
n <- apply(DF[, -1], 1, function(x) if (any(x)) which.max(rev(x) != 0) - 1 else length(x))
#[1] 4 0 1 5 1 2

DF$Clients[n >= 3]
#[1] Client 1 Client 4
#Levels: Client 1 Client 2 Client 3 Client 4 Client 5 Client 6
```

Comment: Can something like this be done with a tidy dataset?  if i've got DF <- DF %>%     gather(var, val, -Clients), can we count the ammount of zero's before first non-zero?

Answer (score 1):

```
data <- data.frame(Clients = c("Client 1",  "Client 2", "Client 3", "Client 4", "Client 5", "Client 6"),
               Jan = c(123,549,500,126,546,0), 
               Feb = c(768,542,0,545,546,0), 
               Mar = c(678,21,500,2315,0,0),
               Apr= c(452,321,0,0,0,25),
               May= c(213,31,500,268,0,78),
               Jun= c(123,59,0,126,328,563),
               Jul= c(55,998,500,56,486,698),
               Aug= c(10,0,0,0,326,631),
               Sep= c(0,546,500,0,0,230),
               Oct= c(0,980,0,0,0,53),
               Nov= c(0,0,500,0,66,0),
               Dec= c(0,987,0,0,0,0))

data_Clean <- data %>%
  mutate(Client_Stat = rowSums(data[,(ncol(data)-2):ncol(data)]))%>%
  mutate(Client_Status = ifelse(Client_Stat < 1,"Left","with us"))
```

In this case you will get only those client from which there were no transactions in last 3 months.

**Description**: We sum up the last 3 columns and checked that if the sum value is greater than 0 than he is with us or else the client left....

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @Дмитрий Перепечин atleast, reply and let us know if this is the same what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea via base R can be,

```
k <- 3
df$Clients[rowSums(df[-c(1:(ncol(df) - k))] == 0) == k]
#[1] Client1 Client4
#Levels: Client1 Client2 Client3 Client4 Client5 Client6
```

---

Also, we can convert to long, get the last 3 values, and `filter` on all those values being 0. Then `pull` the `Clients`. Doing it via `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

k <- 3
v1 <- df %>% 
       gather(var, val, -Clients) %>% 
       group_by(Clients) %>% 
       slice((n()-k):n()) %>% 
       filter(all(val == 0)) %>% 
       pull(Clients)

unique(v1)
#[1] Client1 Client4
#Levels: Client1 Client2 Client3 Client4 Client5 Client6
```